# How to check whether input matches a value in an array

Tags: python

Here is the code I have written so far. As you can see if you run the code, I am having a problem with the last 6 lines and their function.

```
kegsize = input('Please enter keg size. Litres: ')
print (kegsize, 'Litres')

netpurchasecost = input('Please enter net purchase cost. GBP: ')
print ('£', netpurchasecost)

abv = input('Please enter Alcohol by Volume. %: ')
print (abv, '%')

gp = input('Please enter Gross Profit Percentage. %: ')
print (gp, '%')

opt = print('These are the Portion Size options (imperial measurements), 1/3, 1/2, 2/3, 1')
portionsize = input('Please choose Portion Size: ')
if portionsize != ['1/3' , '1/2' , '2/3' , '1']:
    print('Please enter a Portion Size from the list')
else:
    print(portionsize)
```

Regardless of whether I enter a portion size of '1/3','1/2','2/3' or '1' the shell will still output 'Please enter a Portion Size from the list'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
 if portionsize not in ['1/3' , '1/2' , '2/3' , '1']:
```

Comment: exactly what i needed thank you very much
edit: works perfectly